# Storing logged in users information in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am currently implementing session in mvc to store logged in user details. I am am retrieving user information using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and then passing that value to the database to see if it exists. Please note that there is no login screen. If user exist, I am  storing that value in session.

If you see the code below, I am calling the MCRHeler class method from session start event. The code is quite self explanatory from there on.

I would like to know if there is any suggestion or recommendation on the implementation. I would like to also know if I need to handle killing session and if Yes, how to go about it

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userDetails = MCRHelper.UserDetails;

    if (userDetails != null)
        Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
    else
        Response.Redirect("Message/Authorize",false);
}
```

`MCRHelper` class:

```
public static UserDetails UserDetails
{
    get 
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetails"] == null)
        {
            if (IsUserExists())
            {
                var userSessionRepository = new SessionRepository();
                var contactDetails = userSessionRepository.GetUserProfileByNetworkId(GetShortname());
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetails"] = contactDetails;
            }
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetails"] as UserDetails;
    }
}

public static bool IsUserExists()
{
    using (var db = new MCREntities())
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(db.spUserExists(GetShortname(), GetDomain(), 1).FirstOrDefault().UserExists);
    }
}
```

Session repository:

```
public class SessionRepository 
{
    public UserDetails GetUserProfileByNetworkId(string user)
    {
        MCREntities db = new MCREntities();

        var userProfiles = db.spGetUserProfileByNetworkID(user).FirstOrDefault(); 
        return Mapper.Map<UserDetails>(userProfiles);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you login a user without a login screen/mask/form?

Comment: This code does the trick. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. It gets the window user